# why my "onSubmit" & "onChange" function is not calling in react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {useState} from "react";

export function UpdateData(props){
    let [name,setName]=useState(props.usersData.name);
    let [age,setAge]=useState(props.usersData.age);
    let [city,setCity]=useState(props.usersData.city);
    
    let updateSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let url=`http://localhost:8000/update/${props.usersData._id}`;
        axios.put(url,{"name":name,"age":age,"city":city})
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
            document.getElementById("updateForm").innerHTML=`<div class="text-success"><h2>Data updated successfully.</h2></div>`;
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
            document.getElementById("updateForm").innerHTML=`<div class="text-danger"><h2>Sorry some Error occer !! Error: ${err} !!</h2></div>`;
        });
    }
    return(
            <div>
                <div className="updateForm">
                    <form onSubmit={updateSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Your ID:</label>
                            <input name="id" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData._id} placeholder="Enter your name here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="id" readOnly></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Enter your name:</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.name} placeholder="Enter your name here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="name"  
                            onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Enter your age:</label>
                            <input name="age" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.age} placeholder="Enter your age here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="age" 
                            onChange={(e)=>setAge(e.target.value)}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Enter your city:</label>
                            <input name="city" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.city} placeholder="Enter your city here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="city" 
                            onChange={(e)=>setCity(e.target.value)}></input>
                        </div><br/>
                        <div>
                            <button className="btn" id="myButton2">Save Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

When ever I'm clicking on "Save Update" button the  should be submit, and this "updateSubmit" function should perform accordingly. But some how this "updateSubmit" function is not calling. And on the "onChange" function inside  element also not performing. please help by giving some ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<button className="btn" id="myButton2" type="submit">Save Update</button>
```

Without type="submit" it **could** happen that the button is recognized as a normal button that has nothing to do with a form. Especially if you use two or more buttons.
Or you use

```
<input type="submit" value="Save Update" id="myButton2" className="btn" />
```

Comment: still same issue @tom203

Comment: @SOHAMHAZRA okay. I tried now your code on my computer and I don't get any problem if I enter a console.log in your updateSubmit() function. Do you get an output if you do that?

Comment: I have used document.getElementById("updateCont").innerHTML=ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<UpdateData usersData={response.data}/>);
to send the props data, so is that creating the problem ?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 0):

You should not change html with `document.getElementById` in react. Do something like this instead:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

export function App(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(props.usersData.name);
  const [age, setAge] = useState(props.usersData.age);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(props.usersData.city);
  const [success, setSucess] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  let updateSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = `http://localhost:8000/update/${props.usersData._id}`;
    axios.put(url, { "name": name, "age": age, "city": city })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setSucess(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(true);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="updateForm">
        {success && <div className="text-success"><h2>Data updated successfully.</h2></div>}
        {error && <div className="text-danger"><h2>Sorry some Error occer !! Error !!</h2></div>}
        {!success && !error &&
          <form onSubmit={updateSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Your ID:</label>
              <input name="id" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData._id} placeholder="Enter your name here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="id" readOnly></input>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Enter your name:</label>
              <input name="name" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.name} placeholder="Enter your name here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="name"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  console.log(e.target.value);
                  setName(e.target.value)
                }}></input>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Enter your age:</label>
              <input name="age" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.age} placeholder="Enter your age here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="age"
                onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}></input>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Enter your city:</label>
              <input name="city" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.city} placeholder="Enter your city here....." autoComplete="off" className="form-control" id="city"
                onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}></input>
            </div><br />
            <div>
              <button className="btn" id="myButton2" type="submit">Save Update</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You should also make the button to the type submit.

```js
<button className="btn" id="myButton2" type="submit">Save Update</button>
```